# I created a windows form and connect it to database. But I got a error while running

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms

I created a Windows form in Visual Application and connect it to a SQL Server database. But when I running the code shown here, I got an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.)

Code:

```
private void button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [MyTable] (Name, Surename, Address) VALUES ('"+ textBox1.Text +","+ textBox2.Text + "," + textBox3.Text + "')";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();

    textBox1.Text = "";
    textBox2.Text = "";
    textBox3.Text = "";
    textBox4.Text = "";
}
```

I tried to remove some of the values and run it. But it's shows the same error again.

Comment: Do not use string concatenation to create an SQL command. Use parameterized statements. See [why it's a bad idea and how to fix it](//bobby-tables.com).

Comment: debug and inspect the query in `cmd.CommandText`

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend

- Placing data operations into a class, invoke from your form
- Use parameters via `Add` rather than `AddWithValue` rather than string concatenation
- Don't use one connection for all operations but that is your choice.

Here is an example that returns the new primary key.

```
public class DataOperations
{
    private static string _connectionString = "TODO";


    public static int Insert(string name, string surName, string address)
    {
        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            using var cmd = new SqlCommand
            {
                Connection = cn,
                CommandText = "INSERT INTO [MyTable] (Name, Surename, Address) VALUES (@Name, @SurName, @Address);" +
                              "SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);"
            };

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = name;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SurName", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = surName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = address;

            cn.Open();

            return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        }
    }
}
```

While this example inserts a record similar to what you are doing now.

```
public class DataOperations
{
    private static string _connectionString = "TODO";


        public static void Insert(string name, string surName, string address)
        {
            using (var cn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                using var cmd = new SqlCommand
                {
                    Connection = cn,
                    CommandText = "INSERT INTO [MyTable] (Name, Surename, Address) VALUES (@Name, @SurName, @Address);"
                };

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = name;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@SurName", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = surName;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = address;

                cn.Open();

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
}
```